# Do I need to send the data in $.ajax as json?

Tags: ajax, json, forms

I have an $.ajax request that's sending the data in a serialize() and gets a json array in return. It works perfectly without any issues on Chrome develop's tools and Firefox's firebug. My question is, do I HAVE to send the data(user inputs) as json? I need json for the response but not for the request.

Comment: You could send binary data for all that matters.  It just depends on how you set up the processing of that data.

Answer (score 0):

No, you send the data however you like but keep in mind how you send it will affect how you can retrieve it.
Also you aren't sending JSON in your request as `.serialize()` does not return JSON it returns a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

Comment: I used json_encode() for my PDO object array after fetching the data from the table. the content type on the request header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, but for the response is application/json. I just grab the response[i].nameofobject in success. I just don't see the point in sending the data as json.

Comment: @user2836965 do you mean sending the response as json?

Comment: Yes, just the response.

Comment: @user2836965 you don't have to send the request data as json but you aren't actually doing that in the first place.

Comment: I know I'm not doing it, I just want to know if it's a bad practice not to send the data as json if you're gonna receive it as json.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to send it as JSON.  You can send it in any other format, but your receiver will need to know how to interpret it.  Usually people use JSON or XML since your receiver can easily parse these types of data.

You'll need to set the content-type, then you can tell the receiver how to process this content-type.